Regular expression optimization in java code
I have this:
Pattern myPattern =
                Pattern.compile("Customer_[a-zA-Z]+([-_][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(#[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\\.xlsx");

When building the project, SonarQube fails because it says

Refactor this repetition that can lead to a stack overflow for large
inputs.

And marks this area of the regex
(#[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*

And also this part
(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*

I don't know how to optimize this, because SonarCube marks that as a major bug.
Do you know how to fix that?

And as usual, SQ is doing a bad job, simply ignore this. The regex is already optional. You may also just add + after * to make it possessive.

@WiktorStribiżew I cannot skip that unfortunately, so is there no way to optimize this?

It is optimal, Sonar is wrong. It is bad at analyzing regex.

@WiktorStribiżew but isn't there a risk of ReDoS if I purposely use a very, very large input?

What makes you think so?

You can try to ’optimize’ regular expressions all you want, but all regular expressions that recognize the same things compile to the same DFA, by definition.
